# FOR loop to iterate through two folders

Tags: bash, for-loop, comparison

I have two folders to compare, but it's not that simple just to use diff -r to do this.

Instead of a diff, I'm using a small conditional function. Maybe the function itself matters, so I'll paste it here.

```
function timeDiff() {

local time1="$(head -n 1 "$1")"

local time2="$(head -n 1 "$2")"

    echo $time1
  echo $time2

  if (( "$time1" < 60)) && (( "$time2" < 60)); then  

  echo No comparision needed. 

  else

    diff $1 $2

    fi
}
```

Now. I have 2 folders, they currently look like this:

```
Folder name: 1    Folder name: 2
1.txt             1.txt
2.txt             2.txt
```

And here is my salt in the eye. The second function. It's purposes are (may contain pseudocode):

1. In a for loop iterate through both folders, take the first file `1.txt`, check if there is a file having the same name `1.txt` in the second folder, if it does, run the `timeDiff` function on them, and go to the next files (``` 1/2.txt``2/2.txt ```) and so on and on and on.

For now the second function is looking like this:

```
function recuDiff() {
    for file1 in $1 && file2 in $2
    do
     timeDiff $file1 $file2
    done

}
```

I tried several times but I don't seem to find a way to at least run the for loop with multiple conditions...

Comment: @SandyElms: sorry, added it by mistake. There is no occurence of it in the original code ;)

Comment: The `in` keyword in the `for` loop does not check if a file exists in a directory. Read the [`bash` man pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function recuDiff {
  find 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\n' |
  while read each
  do
    if [ -e 2/"$each" ]
    then
      timeDiff {1,2}/"$each"
    fi
  done
}
```

1. find thing in `1`
2. if thing exists in `2`, run `timeDiff`

However I must say the better/easier thing to do would be to just put a check
for non-existent files in `timeDiff`.

Comment: @dziki see my last sentence, I just added it